# ANR analysis, issue reported on Play Developer Console

Tags: android

There is one ANR report which I need help to understand it. It is only happened to this user so far. Under the main thread, I can't find anything related to my app package.

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x7392f2a0 self=0xb8bdcd80
  | sysTid=1973 nice=-2 cgrp=native sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f3cb34
  | state=S schedstat=( 52372964435 58689172479 125804 ) utm=3878 stm=1359 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe395000-0xbe397000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/1973/stack)
  native: #00 pc 00042f0c  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+20)
  native: #01 pc 0001967f  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+26)
  native: #02 pc 0001968d  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+6)
  native: #03 pc 00012da3  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+102)
  native: #04 pc 0001301f  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+130)
  native: #05 pc 00083ed1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+22)
  native: #06 pc 00000585  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+96)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:288)
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:173)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

And I noticed this thread which is blocked. However, I don't know how to trace from there.

```
"HeapTaskDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Blocked
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c041c0 self=0xb8c02318
  | sysTid=1982 nice=0 cgrp=native sched=0/0 handle=0xb40c3930
  | state=S schedstat=( 68261230481 5881920066 14105 ) utm=6561 stm=265 core=7 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb3fc1000-0xb3fc3000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/1982/stack)
  native: #00 pc 000169b8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 000f60bb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
  native: #02 pc 001cdff1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor7GetTaskEPNS_6ThreadE+92)
  native: #03 pc 001ce505  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+60)
  native: #04 pc 00000387  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+74)
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
  - waiting to lock an unknown object
  at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:355)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here is the complete file. Thanks for the input.
[ANR file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8shbq9Sw2lgNkY4MHBCemNkZWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Were you able to figure the cause ? We have the exact same issue